# Resuming the download using Internet Download Manager

Tags: firefox, download, file-transfer, download-manager

Q:

I use IDM (Internet Download Manager version 5.18 Build 8) to download files, but when I download a file from MediaFire.com for example, the connection is sometimes cut.

When I try to resume the downloading, the following message is shown:

```
the website send a web page instead of a file when IDM requested this file second time
```

Is there any way to resume the partial download without having to restart the download from the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things to try -

1. Upgrade to IDM v6, the resume capability is lot better. It still won't prevent the above message from showing up - that's because MediaFire expires the download link shortly. What you can do is -
2. Right click on the file in the queue that was cutoff from download and select Refresh download address. That should open the web browser to the page where you had originally downloaded it from. More often than not, it might show that the page has expired. If so, start downloading the file from the original link. Once IDM intercepts the file download, it should resume from where it had cut off.

Answer (score -1):

I use [Internet Download Manager](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/) for downloading content from sites. It supports resuming downloads from sites that support resuming downloads.

However note that some sites do not support resumable downloads.

Comment: could u summarize it as answer?the faq link which you have linked contains enormous questions

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Please don't provide link only answers. Links can break which means your answer becomes useless to future visitors. Add a summary or abridged version of the relevant contents of the link.